# Survey123 Connect-fieldLength doesn't seem to work

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I'm working on my first webform using Survey123 Connect and am struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'd like to change the length of some of the entry fields so if I am asking them to enter their age, it doesn't take up the entire width of the page as it does now.

I tried using the `bind::esri:fieldLength`, assuming that entering a number in that field would limit the entry to that number of characters. Is there something else I need to do to put that into effect?

[image: an example of what I've tried so far]

With those values entered, all the entry fields still take up the entire width of the page. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

The bind::esri:fieldLength column is used to specify the field length for the feature class that Survey123 will automatically create when published.  To see changes in the field length in your feature class I think you have to publish the changes after you save the form.

you are correct in this limits the max characters (for strings) of the form, but I don't think it modifies the form appearance.

There is a new advanced XLS form with a new appearance tab in version 3.10 of Survey123 Connect that should let you modify the appearance.

https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2020/08/07/updated-xlsform-templates-for-survey123

It looks like you can change the grid options and I think that may be what you are ultimately looking for.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformsappearance.htm

I did see somewhere that you could do some html now as well, but I can't speak to that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I understand now.

I was expecting the appearance of the form to change as it does for other changes I've made in Survey123 Connect. I can't publish it myself, and was trying to get that resolved before asking for it to be published. 

I guess I'll go ahead and ask for it to be published and see if it looks the way I want it to.